# Using <f:selectitems> in html to make dependent drop down list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to select a value from one drop down and depending on its value, able to disable another drop down list. but what i want is that when the 2nd drop down is disabled it should show '(select one)'.

This is my code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="tier" isRequired="true"
                                value="#{allocationTemplateDetailsBackingBean.allocationRule.allocationFulfillParameters.fulfillmentTierStr}">
                                <f:selectItems id="tierList"
                                    value="#{allocationTemplateDetailsBackingBean.fulfillmentTierList}" />
....
...
</h:selectOneMenu>

and the javascript function is as follows:

function controlFulfillmentTierDropDownList() 
        {
            var strategy = document.getElementById('dataForm:strategy');
            if(strategy != null)
            {
                if(strategy.value == 5)
                {

                    var fulfillmentTierDropDownList = document.getElementById('dataForm:tier');
                    fulfillmentTierDropDownList.disabled = true;

                    var supplyTypePanel = document.getElementById('supplyTypeDiv');
                    supplyTypePanel.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
```

from the tierList, the first value in the list is '(Select one)', so whenever strategy.value==5, i want to disable tierlist dropdown (which i have done by disable attribute of tier), but want to set the value which is visible as '(select one)' instead of any older value which is already present.